# Does QGIS have anything like Geodatabase Versioning?

Tags: qgis, versioning

I am just wondering if QGIS has anything like Esri's geodatabase versioning?

Comment: No, edits are made directly to the tables themselves. This causes a problem when Esri and QGIS are editing the same database: the Esri users are aware of the QGIS edits immediately but the QGIS users cannot access the Esri edits until they are compressed to base.

Comment: It's more complicated than that, Michael -- Edits made in QGIS to rows edited in a version wouldn't be seen by ArcGIS Desktop/Server, ever, and would be silently deleted upon reconcile/compress.

Comment: @Vince that would be dangerous. I'm glad I never tried it.